# Is there a way to convert white to transparent in Paint shop pro 9?

Tags: paint-shop-pro

i have an image with a white background (its a png).  Is there anyway in Paint shop Pro 9 to convert this white background to transparent?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the white area (say using the Magic Wand) and deleting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Paint Shop Pro 5 & 7 (don't have a version here to give exact instructions from - going from memory) you had to go into one of the menu's and 'Set Transparency', you would they select which colour from the palette to make transparent.

You might want to change the background to another colour if there are other white areas you don't wish to be transparent.

You might also have to change the image type to .jpg to do it...

Comment: For Paint Shop Pro 9 this is incorrect. The correct answer is funkymonkey0073´s answer

Answer (score 1):

Image > Palette > Set Transparency , then select the colour you want to be transparent.

Comment: This answer is totally correct for Paint Shop Pro 9!

Comment: Works well for Paint Shop Pro 8 also.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:
a) make a square selection that involves only the white background
b) Go to Selection > Modify > Select Similar
c) Select "discontinuous" option

Now al the white will be selected. 
Just press "delete" and white will be turned to transparent